# Trying to get property of non-object in PHP works well with iOS but not in android

Tags: php, android, ios, json, facebook

I am using Android Facebook SDK to get facebook friends.

After getting facebook friends I am sending it in a JSON string as input to PHP web service as given below.

**JSON input**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "fbUsername": "test",
      "is_app_user": "false",
      "name": "test",
      "pic_square": "https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-prn2\/t5.0-1\/test.jpg",
      "uid": "456464515482",
      "userId": "42"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I send it via iOS appliation it works fine, but if I send it via Android it's not getting decoded from web service end.

**PHP web service** code is given below.

```
$post_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$reqData[] = json_decode($post_body);
$userdata = $reqData[0];
```

In android data I am getting data in `$post_body` but not decoded in `$reqData`. But it works well in iOS application.

I am getting error as given below.

[image]

```
@$error=0;
$friendsArray = $userdata->data; // Line number 645

foreach ($friendsArray as $fbUser) // Line number 647
{
  .....
}
// where $userdata = $reqData[0];
```

Can anybody please suggest me what is the wrong with my coding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us some lines (related to lines 645 & 647) in the file D:\wamp\...\file.php

Comment: I have added lines in question.

Comment: do double check if you get the correct input `$post_body = file_get_contents('php://input');` both on iOS and android.

Comment: Yes, I am getting correct input from both android and iOS. I am getting `JSON_ERROR_UTF8` error.

Comment: ah, there you got the specific error. try to encode the input using `utf8_encode` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php